# Comment out part of a line in R

Tags: r, comments

I would like to comment our a part of a command line of my code in R.

Is there any way of doing this?

take the following example:
Can I comment out `+100` from my first line?

```
library(tidyverse)
data%>%mutate(sum1=1+10+100,
sum2=2+20+200)
```

In this comment it was explained that it is possible to comment out splitting the command into multiple lines [Is it possible to comment out part of a line in R/RStudio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50768050/is-it-possible-to-comment-out-part-of-a-line-in-r-rstudio)
something like this

```
library(tydiverse)

data%>%mutate(sum1=1+10
#+100
,sum2=2+20+200)
```

but this is not what I want to do.
I would like to keep the same lines and comment out `+100`

Does anyone knows how to do it?

thanks a lot

Comment: R doesn't have an end comment character like `someCode /* a comment */ moreCode` in other languages, so no you can't do this.

Comment: @SamR Post as answer? Also @Alex: it's `tidyverse` not `tydiverse`.

Comment: Insert `0*` before `100` or insert `FALSE*` instead or just `!`.

Comment: Why not just initialize the sum1 values as variables and then just set the variable you don't want included to 0?  So n1 = 1, n2 = 10, n3 = 100 OR 0;  sum1 = n1 + n2 + n3.

Comment: I am looking for a general way of commenting out part of the command line, the code I have written is just an example. Solutions specific to this line of code (`0*100`) do not address the question unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this? It might be bad form, but it would work. Also, I know the `#rhs` does not actually do anything in the inline operator, but I put it there just to illustrate the idea. Someone smarter than me might actually be able to make an inline comment function. In essence, the `%com%` function is just skipping the next operation.

```r
library(tidyverse)

`%com%` <- function(lhs, rhs){
  lhs #rhs
}

tibble(x = "test") %>%
  mutate(sum1=1 + 10 + 100 + 1000,
         sum2= 1 + 10 + 100 %com%+ 1000,
         sum3= 1 + 10 %com%+ 100 + 1000)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 4
#>   x      sum1  sum2  sum3
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 test   1111   111  1011
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>