# How could we place a comment and a new line of code on the same line

Tags: r, comments

There is no special background, I am just curious if there are any considerations regarding this:

To the best of my knowledge, in R, it is not possible to include a comment and a new line of code on the same line [see comment @Ben Bolker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50768050/is-it-possible-to-comment-out-part-of-a-line-in-r-rstudio), as demonstrated in this example:

[image]

I found this from [2018 stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50768050/is-it-possible-to-comment-out-part-of-a-line-in-r-rstudio)
and
this from [2022 stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73518916/comment-out-part-of-a-line-in-r). The latter using a custom funtion `%com%` that did not work for me:

```
library(dplyr)

`%com%` <- function(lhs, rhs){
  lhs #rhs
}

mtcars %>% 
  select(cyl, mpg, %com%am, wt) %>% 
  head()

Error: unexpected SPECIAL in:
"mtcars %>% 
  select(cyl, mpg, %com%"
```

I usually do like:

```
mtcars %>% 
  select(cyl, mpg, 
         #am, 
         wt) %>% 
  head()
```

Comment: The `%com%` function needs a symbol on the left hand side to work. It won't work in the context you have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commenting facility of R is hard-coded into the parser. We can't really cheat the parser, but we can give the user the illusion that we are. We can set up a system whereby the symbols `.%\%'` open a comment, and `'%\%.` close it.

So for example:

```r
mtcars %>% 
  select(cyl, mpg, .%\%' am, wt '%\%.) %>% 
  head()
#>                   cyl  mpg
#> Mazda RX4           6 21.0
#> Mazda RX4 Wag       6 21.0
#> Datsun 710          4 22.8
#> Hornet 4 Drive      6 21.4
#> Hornet Sportabout   8 18.7
#> Valiant             6 18.1
```

The implementation would be something like:

```r
`%\\%` <- function(a, b) {
  
  mc <- as.list(match.call())
  if(deparse(mc$a) == "." & deparse(mc$b) == ".") return(invisible(NULL))
  if(deparse(mc$a) != "." & deparse(mc$b) != ".")
    stop("could not find function `%\\%")
  
  if(deparse(mc$a) == ".") {
    if(!is.character(mc$b)) stop("could not find function .%\\%")
    return(invisible(NULL))
  }
  eval(mc$a)
}
```

Of course, this is a bit unwieldy for regular use, unless you set up a comment / uncomment macro in your IDE. There are also places where it might cause a syntax error, or the fact that it invisibly returns NULL could give unexpected results, so I wouldn't actually use this myself - it's just an illustration of one type of approach.

Comment: Fantastic and wonderful!!

Answer (score 1):

If this is about including/excluding an element without deleting code, you could set element to `NULL`.

```
> f <- \(x, include=TRUE) if (include) x else NULL
> subset(mtcars, select=c(cyl, mpg, f(am), wt)) |> head()
                  cyl  mpg am    wt
Mazda RX4           6 21.0  1 2.620
Mazda RX4 Wag       6 21.0  1 2.875
Datsun 710          4 22.8  1 2.320
Hornet 4 Drive      6 21.4  0 3.215
Hornet Sportabout   8 18.7  0 3.440
Valiant             6 18.1  0 3.460
> subset(mtcars, select=c(cyl, mpg, f(am, F), wt)) |> head()
                  cyl  mpg    wt
Mazda RX4           6 21.0 2.620
Mazda RX4 Wag       6 21.0 2.875
Datsun 710          4 22.8 2.320
Hornet 4 Drive      6 21.4 3.215
Hornet Sportabout   8 18.7 3.440
Valiant             6 18.1 3.460
> inc <- FALSE
> subset(mtcars, select=c(cyl, mpg, f(am, inc), f(wt, inc))) |> head()
                  cyl  mpg
Mazda RX4           6 21.0
Mazda RX4 Wag       6 21.0
Datsun 710          4 22.8
Hornet 4 Drive      6 21.4
Hornet Sportabout   8 18.7
Valiant             6 18.1
```